# minix doesn't shut down

Tags: unix, virtual-machine, shutdown, minix

I've installed minix on virtual machine (bochs VM). Everything works great until I try to shut down the minix (shutdown command). Minix hangs at this output

```
MINIX will now be shut down...
```

What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please include the command and options used as well.

Comment: Possible solution: http://serverfault.com/questions/191537/shutdown-what-is-difference-between-power-off-and-halt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 shutdown -p
```

works. Maybe there are more options but I must check them.